# Key won't come out of a Ford Fusion, 2007

Tags: ford, key

The keys are stuck in the ignition in this vehicle, even when the car is in park. What can be done to fix this, so the keys can come out again? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried jiggling the starter switch, to make sure it's in the locked position?

Comment: It seems to be related to the gear shifter, the system doesn't seem to register it being in park somehow...

Comment: Can you get the keys out with it in neutral then?

Comment: So, are you saying the switch won't come back to the locked position at all?  If so, I'd try @jzd's suggestion - see if you can do it in neutral. Also, make regular use of your parking brake until the root cause is resolved.

Comment: Just tried removing the bezel ring and pulled out a little plastic piece that had broken off the bezel ring and it worked the key came out of the ignition the piece that broke off is actually one of two parts that hold the bezel ring in place it would be easy to replace a new bezel ring. Thanks a lot it was a simple solution and didn't cost a penny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by jzd in a comment, try removing the key when in Neutral rather than Park.
If trying while in Park, try to ensure you are in Park and the car knows that it's in Park. Does anything else usually happen when Park is engaged? A dashlight or something else to indicate that the car knows it is in Park.
Another thing to try is giving the steering wheel a bit of jiggle, sometimes the steering lock can 'jam' keys, although usually this is more of a problem when inserting keys and starting rather then removing.

Comment: The steering wheel jiggle was what did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well.  There is a little bezel ring around the push button on the shifter.  Pull it out slightly and the key will come out.